# having issue looping through json objects

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js

I have array like following

```
  var data = [
            {
                title: 'This is title',
                desc: 'This is desc',
                date: '07:12'
            },
            {
                title: 'This is title2',
                desc: 'This is desc2',
                date: '04:12'
            },
            {
                title: 'This is title3',
                desc: 'This is desc3',
                date: '09:12'
            }
        ];
```

Now I want to loop through this data to display using underscorejs templates. I am trying following which is not working.

```
<% _.each(function () { %>
        <li>
            <span class="time"><%= date %></span>
            <p><%= title %></p>
            <p><%= desc %></p>
        </li>
    <% }); %>
```

The code above does not display anything and it also does not show any error in console. How can I loop through this array data to show all the data?

**UPDATE**

Here is some more code. I am passing this data from backbone view

```
var Message = Backbone.View.extend({
    className: 'tops',

    render: function () {
        console.log(this.model.toJSON()); //<-- see output for this below
        this.$el.html(_.template(MessageTemplate, this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});
```

console.log() output

```
Object {title: "This is title", desc: "This is desc", date: "07:12"} message.js:6
Object {title: "This is title2", desc: "This is desc2", date: "04:12"} message.js:6
Object {title: "This is title3", desc: "This is desc3", date: "09:12"}
```

I am passing above objects to my template and then looping through it to show.

Comment: That is not valid JSON. Are those objects supposed to be in an array?

Comment: Please see the documentation of `_.each` http://underscorejs.org/#each

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the object you're looping through:

```
<% _.each(data,function (elem) { %>
    <li>
        <span class="time"><%= elem.date %></span>
        <p><%= elem.title %></p>
        <p><%= elem.desc %></p>
    </li>
<% }); %>
```

See the [underscore documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#each).

Comment: this shows this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined`

Comment: This makes me suspect there is something else wrong with the rest of your code. I've tried writing a simple test on my box and it worked. Would you mind creating a simplified jsfiddle illustrating your problem?

Comment: Actually that is not a json object. That is an array.

Comment: Who said anything about a JSON object? Would you please create a fiddle illustrating your problem or at least post more code? Otherwise I will not be able to help you

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum You also need to pass in the object to the `_.each` http://underscorejs.org/#template.

Comment: @x4ph4r Can you try this again and let me know if my edit helped?

Comment: Now it says `Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined`

Comment: @x4ph4r How are you calling _.template? Are you doing so like _.template(templateString, {data:data})  where templateString is the above template and data is your data variable?

Comment: I am receiving Backbone model from another view. which has that data objects separately as shown in the output above in my post. So I am not passing data, I am passing individual objects.

Answer (score 0):

From [underscorejs.org](http://underscorejs.org/#template)

> When you evaluate a template function, pass in a data object that has
>   properties corresponding to the template's free variables. If you're
>   writing a one-off, you can pass the data object as the second
>   parameter to template in order to render immediately instead of
>   returning a template function.

The underscore code you use in your template works the same way it does as if you were to write it out normally. `_.each` requires a minimum of two arguments. First the list of items you wan to iterator over, and second an action to take on each item.

```
_.each([1, 2, 3], alert);
```

You need to do the same with your template.

```
<% _.each(dataSet, function (item) { %>
    <li>
        <span class="time"><%= item.date %></span>
        <p><%= item.title %></p>
        <p><%= item.desc %></p>
    </li>
<% }); %>

var rendered_html = _.template(template, {dataSet: data})
```

Notice how the second object passed into `_.template` contains a key of `dataSet`. The keys we pass into `_.template` can be used in our template code to reference the value associated with them.

You can see an example here: http://jsbin.com/upugaz/1/edit

Comment: above shows this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined`

Comment: That is probably because data is not defined... check the jsbin link.

Comment: This isn't a fully featured backbone example, but it should help you. http://jsbin.com/upugaz/3/edit

Comment: This seems working to some extent. However when I `<% console.log(title) %>` inside `_.each()` inside template. The it shows `title, description and date` for all objects. Thus `item.title, item.desc and item.time` does not work. Why?

Answer (score 0):

You've got to give a name to the array when passing it into the template:

```
this.$el.html(_.template(MessageTemplate, { 'items': this.model.toJSON() }));
```

Now you can reference the array you want to loop over inside your template:

```
<% _.each(items, function (item) { %>
    <li>
        <span class="time"><%= item.date %></span>
        <p><%= item.title %></p>
        <p><%= item.desc %></p>
    </li>
<% }); %>
```